# Rational Non-Integral Root

Tags: polynomials, roots

Prove by contradiction that the following equation with integral coefficients can not have a rational but non integral root.

$x^{n}+p_{n-1}x^{n-1}+p_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots +p_{0}=0$

Comment: What do you already know, and what have you tried?

Comment: If $n=1$ and $p_0 = -1$, then $x^1+p_0=0$ has rational and integral root.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: I suppose the $p_n$ are primes?

Comment: No, it works for all integer polynomials with leading coefficient 1. Actually, all integer roots are divisors of $p_0$ which is an often used technique for text book problems.